# Python Novice: where to start with Python and TwitterAPI

Tags: python, github, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have been successfully using the Python Tweepy library to download data (tweets) from Twitter. I had substantial help with my code using Tweepy. For the next stage of my research, I need to access the Premium Search API, which I cannot do using Tweepy. Twitter recommends using TwitterAPI for premium search, available from @geduldig on GitHub. The problem is I'm new to Python and it would be a steep learning curve for me to learn TwitterAPI. Am I able to use TwitterAPI just to access the premium search API, but use Tweepy for other tasks (implement search query, etc)?

Comment: Unless you plan to use the 30day sandbox api, which is very limited, you'll have to pay, at least, 149USD. https://developer.twitter.com/en/pricing/search-30day

Comment: Thank you, I plan to pay. I just wanted to see if I could my script to work first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know specifics about the libraries you asked, but of course, you could use both the libraries in your program.

You need to spend a little bit more time grokking the TwitterAPI library. I do not think that amounts to a steep learning curve.

Comment: Thank you. It is not that the library is difficult, but that I am not familiar with Python.

Comment: A bunch of short, useful examples here https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/tree/master/examples. Once you have your API keys these examples should all give you results.